# How to manipulate data extracted from a text file using fstream in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to make a Point of Sale software which is reading product names, barcodes and prices from a given text file. I can extract all the required data from the file, but I don't know how to use that data. To be precise I need to calculate the prices of picked products. My program is currently able to ask a user for a barcode and print out the chosen products

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void KeyWord(ifstream &FileSearch)
{
    string line;
    string letters[5];
    ifstream readSearch;

    cout<< "Enter a barcode of a product: \n";
    cin >> letters[0];
    cin >> letters[1];
    cin >> letters[2];
    cin >> letters[3];
    cin >> letters[4];
    readSearch.open("Products.txt");
    if(readSearch.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(readSearch, line))
        {
            while (line.find(letters[0])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[1])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[2])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[3])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[4])!=string::npos)
            {
                cout << line << "\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file("Products.txt");
    KeyWord(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If each line contains a set of product names, barcodes and prices, get the `line` into an `std::stringstream` and move on from there.

Comment: Try to include some example code and be more descriptive about what "move on from there" means. +1 if you do that.